# python regex,dictionary not inserting into mysql

Tags: python, mysql, regex, dictionary

I obtaines a dictionary 'p' from the following code,but cannot able to insert into the mysql database.please help me to insert the datas into database.

dictionary is :[('Casssandraw', 'Cooking'), ('Archanea', 'Playing'), ('Adarshan', 'Programming'), ('Leelal', 'Baking')]
should be stored to Names and Hobby fields.

```
Name       Hobby
Cassandraw Cooking
Archanea   Playing
...        ...
```

Program:

```
import MySQLdb
import re
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                     user="root", # your username
                      passwd="mysql", # your password
                      db="sakila") # n

with open('qwer2.txt','r') as file, db as cursor:
    f = open('qwer2.txt', 'r')

    lines = f.readlines()

    for x in lines:
       p=re.findall(r'(?:name is|me)\s+(\w+).*?(?:interest|hobby)\s+is\s+(\w+)',x, re.I)
       print p

       cursor.execute(
       '''INSERT INTO Details (Names, Hobby)
          VALUES (%s, %s)''',
         (name, hobby))#<-donot know what to provide
db.commit()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [python regex re.findall() insert data to db](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24724308/python-regex-re-findall-insert-data-to-db)

Comment: yes ,but modified and doenot inserts to database

Comment: Then you might want to try the other question you asked already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24722586/regex-parse-store-in-mysql

Comment: this question infact doesnt have over the entire stackoverflow for sure.

Comment: I'm not convinced, how about this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405875/python-cannot-insert-string-in-table

Comment: infact,the question is clear,none of them provides over how to directly insert a database from a dictionary 'p'.All answers having some source of address,but how do i address the p having 2 values inside seperately and adds to database?

Answer (score 0):

What's the value of 'p'? I assume 'p' is something like:

```
print(p)
>>> [('Casssandraw', 'Cooking'), ('Archanea', 'Playing'), ('Adarshan', 'Programming'), ('Leelal', 'Baking')]
```

Then:

```
value_parm = ','.join(['(%s,%s)'] * len(p))
sql = 'INSERT INTO Details (Names, Hobby) VALUES %s' % value_parm
# print(sql)
# >>> INSERT INTO Details (Names, Hobby) VALUES (%s,%s),(%s,%s),(%s,%s),(%s,%s)
import itertools
flat_p = itertools.chain.from_iterable(p)
# flat_p is an iterable like ['Casssandraw', 'Cooking', 'Archanea', ...]
db.cursor().execute(sql, flat_p)
db.commit()
```